# How to convert file format ascii text to ascii english text in UNIX

Tags: postgresql, unix

I have two files file1 and file2.

file1 format is ascii text.

file2 format is ascii english text.

When I import the data into a table file1 successfully inserted,
but file2 is not imported getting error like format error.

How to convert ascii text to ascii english text?

Give me the command.....

How to convert file format ascii text to ascii english text in UNIX?

Can anyone please tell me?

Comment: I presume there is no need to convert. English characters are in first 128 characters of ascii table.

Comment: BTW, iconv command is used to convert from one encoding to another.

Comment: ASCII is, by definition, for encoding English. There is only one kind, so if your file is encoded in ASCII, you're already done. Did you mean that your file is encoded with a non-ascii, but 8 bit per letter, codepage? For instance, most European languages use a codepage that is similar to ASCII, but not quite the same.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the ASCII text you have and what you want it converted into?

Comment: actually i have two files file 1 and file2    file1 format is ascii text and file2 format is ascii english text

Comment: when i insert the data into a table file1 is sucessfully imported but file2 is getting error like file format error

Comment: can u please tell me command how to convert that

Comment: Please provide excerpts of those files and the error you get. It would also help if you specify your DBMS and the command you use to import files. You've tagged your question with only unix tag so far.